# NumPy package gives an array() error how to fix this?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

This is a sample code to perform Binarization of data using Techniques for Data Preprocessing :

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.preprocessing

input_data = np.array([2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
                      [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
                      [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
                      [5.9, 2.3, -5.8])
# Binarization of Data
data_binarized = preprocessing.binarizer(threshold  = 0.5 ).transform(input_data)
print("\nBinarized Data\n", data_binarized)
```

This code gives an error:

```
array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

How can I make arrays with more than one row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be one more pair of brackets, like this:

```
np.array([[2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
          [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
          [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
          [5.9, 2.3, -5.8]])
```